# filtering by filesize & question about number encoding in r

Tags: r

i have to filter a few hundred thousand csv files by rowlength.
most csv have `13rows *3columns`.
the problem is that i have to filter them without opening the files to check because i need to know the filename of the "offending" (i.e. too short) file.

so my idea was to just select by file size

```
Bytes  419   420   421   422   423   451   452   453   454   455   456   457   478   487   488   489   490   491 
Frequ   10    37   171   216   168    17    37   180   308  1036   435   389     1  8071  9576 37545  4885  3516
```

tests show that files `>= 478 bytes` are all `13 rows` long.
so far so good.

the problem is, that in some of the smaller file sizes, specifically between 451 & 452 bytes some files with 13 rows can be found. as there are only 54 files between 451 & 452 it can of course be done manually  by opening it file by file but i have to repeat this on quite a few variations of datasets so an automated solution would be great.

i noticed, that the 13 row data frames which were/are "hiding" in that file size range do not have decimals in the 3rd column.  (shown below - there are 2 data frames just copied together and divided by nrows column)

```
  DATES_451by    x   y_no_decimals nrows DATES_491by    x   y_with_decimals
1   2007-01-01 148.25           108    13  2007-01-01  57.88           65.31
2   2008-01-01 280.23           206    13  2008-01-01 160.51          176.46
3   2009-01-01 277.79           216    13  2009-01-01 166.81          177.00
4   2010-01-01 302.33           218    13  2010-01-01 165.59          183.65
5   2011-01-01 273.73           208    13  2011-01-01 158.50          158.50
6   2012-01-01 286.23           218    13  2012-01-01 150.00          156.00
7   2013-01-01 283.17           218    13  2013-01-01 154.23          174.37
8   2014-01-01 293.47           217    13  2014-01-01 187.28          187.41
9   2015-01-01 297.75           218    13  2015-01-01 188.50          188.96
10  2016-01-01 291.31           218    13  2016-01-01 177.84          182.34
11  2017-01-01 278.58           215    13  2017-01-01 176.31          182.58
12  2018-01-01 274.54           217    13  2018-01-01 166.66          177.21
13  2019-01-01 180.00           110    13  2019-01-01 100.38          105.77
```

my theory is that the lack of decimals in row 3 is causing this discrepancy in file size.
i tested this with `object.size()` by coercing the 3rd column to integer and compared it with a "regular" 13row data frame.
as all numerics are encoded with 56bytes i could not confirm this but the encoding only becomes viable once read in so it might still be the case. what do you guys think?

can anyone think of a way to select for them anyway?

Comment: `object.size` is about the allocated space in RAM for the object in an R session, not the size of the corresponding data in a csv file (which is just a text file). Making precise inferences about the structure of a csv file based simply on its file size seems unlikely to be reliable. If these files are under your control, why not adopt a naming convention where the names contain the requisite info?

Comment: that might be possible but their names are already quite long containing all sorts of meta information. i am trying to create a loop which goes file by file, opens the file and saves the file name if it detects nrow(13)==T but this is painfully slow

Comment: To cut down on the time you could limit yourself to reading only the first column. Of course I do not know how much time that saves (vs. the accessing the file to begin with).

Comment: You could perhaps use `readLines(fname,n = 14)`. This will read up to 14 lines, keeping the data as simple text (and hence not incurring the cost of e.g. converting from strings to floats). Just check the length of the resulting vector.

Comment: @JohnColeman with the file by file approach no conversion is necessary - everything is read in as character. 

got the time per 70k csv trench down to approx. 3.5min (which is still slow but not a desaster) - will test with `select/drop` as per @MarioNiepel `s idea. thanks guys!

Comment: Might be a use-case for `rcpp`. Creating any R data structure to determine the number of lines might be overkill. If there is a fast C++ solution, you should be able to use it from R.